# Backbone subview events not firing

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

For some reason my view events are not firing and I don't know what is wrong...

Here is the code:

```js
TasksView = ****.Views.BaseView.extend({
    id: 'log-container',
    className: 'row-fluid',
    initialize : function(){
        this.task_selection_view = new TaskSelectionView();
    },
    remove : function(){
        this.task_selection_view.remove();
        Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);
    },
    render : function(){
        $(this.el).html(Templates['log/log']);
        $('#selection',this.el).append(this.task_selection_view.render().el);
        return this;
    }
});


TaskSelectionView = ****.Views.BaseView.extend({
    className : 'row-fluid',
    events : {
        'click #fire' : 'fire'
    },
    render: function(){
        $(this.el).html(Templates['log/task_selection']);
        return this;
    },
    fire : function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('fire');
    }
});
```

`log` template:

```html
<div id="selection"></div>
```

`task_selection` template:

```html
<button id="fire" class="btn btn-default">fire</button>
```

I tried a lot of things but could not understand what the problem is...

Comment: everything looks fine, create a fiddle to demonstrate the issue. Also, show your template.

Comment: The templates are shown in the question...
It looks like the the DOM elements don't bind to events...
with this line "this.delegateEvents();" it works perfectly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you're unknowingly unbinding the subview's events. The call to jQuery's `.html()` will call `.empty()` under the hood, which will detach any DOM events binded to the (subview's) elements.

That's why the problem is resolved when calling `this.delegateEvents()`. You can solve this elegantly by calling `subview.setElement()`, which calls `.delegateEvents()` for you.

In your main view, just replace:

```js
$('#selection',this.el).append(this.task_selection_view.render().el);
```

with:

```js
this.task_selection_view.setElement(this.$('#selection')).render();
```

Here's that line in context (see the `render` function):

```js
TasksView = ****.Views.BaseView.extend({
    id: 'log-container',
    className: 'row-fluid',
    initialize: function () {
        this.task_selection_view = new TaskSelectionView();
    },
    remove: function () {
        this.task_selection_view.remove();
        Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);
    },
    render: function () {
        $(this.el).html(Templates['log/log']);
        this.task_selection_view.setElement(this.$('#selection')).render();
        return this;
    }
});
```

#### Further reading

- *[Rendering Views In Backbone Isn't Always Simple](http://ianstormtaylor.com/rendering-views-in-backbonejs-isnt-always-simple/)* by *Ian Storm Taylor*